# RVM Errno::EACCESS pry pry-doc

Tags: ruby, pry, coderay

I got this error message while attempting to perform a global install of pry and pry-doc.

```
new-host-3:~ UzoAgu$ rvm gemset use global
Using ruby-2.0.0-p247 with gemset global
new-host-3:~ UzoAgu$ gem install pry pry-doc
Fetching: coderay-1.1.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /Users/UzoAgu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/cache/coderay-1.1.0.gem
```

Searching online reveals that pry depends on coderay. Does the above error mean that I have the wrong version of coderay for the particular version of pry-doc I am downloading?

I also noticed that the only gemset in my global is fastercsv.  Could this be an issue also?

Thank you

Comment: No, this means that the user you are logged in as does not have permission to add entries to the global gem cache.

Comment: do `chown UzoAgu /Users/UzoAgu/.rvm/ -R`, then redo installation

Comment: When I follow your instructions, I get back the message `no such file or directory`. Working on using google to figure out what is going on. 

PS: when you say redo installation, you are referring to the gem install right? 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved this issue:

```
 chown UzoAgu /Users/UzoAgu/.rvm/ -R
```

and then I ran

```
bundle install
```

The above two steps resolved the permission denied error message.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions:)